# What credentials does ActiveMerchant need for a Rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, activemerchant

In my credit card processing file, I have:

```
  response = PaymentGateway.pay_pal.authorize(
    foreign_currency_amount_in_cents,
    credit_card,
    :email => email_address,
    :order_id => invoice_number,
    :description => item_id,
    :ip => ip_address,
    :currency => foreign_currency.name,
    :custom_code => credit_card.type
  )
```

In `payment_gateway.rb`, I have

```
class PaymentGateway
  class << self
    def pay_pal
      @pay_pal ||= ActiveMerchant::Billing::PaypalGateway.new(:login => AppConfig.pay_pal[:login], :password => AppConfig.pay_pal[:password])
    end
end
```

In my `environments/production.rb`, I'm assigning a lot more variables to the pay_pal config, specifically:

```
signature: "somesignature"
login: "my.name_api1.mysite.com"
password: "SOMEPASSWORD"
business: "my.name@mysite.com"
business_id: "BUSINESSID"
cert_id: "SOMECERTID"
private_key: |
  -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
  MIICWwIBAA...
  -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

public_key: |
  -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
  MIIDGD...
  -----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I'm trying to switch PayPal accounts and have created a new PayPal account. Do I literally need to just switch the credentials in my environment file? If so, which credentials do I use? The login is not an email address and what I use to login to PayPal is an email address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watch this video here:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/144-active-merchant-basics

It provides step by step instructions on how to get and setup your PayPal API credentials for ActiveMerchant.

Also PayPal gives you the information 
MyAccount -> Profile -> API Access -> Request API Credentials

For more info also see:
https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/apicertificates